# __COUNTER__ with global scope

Tags: c, gnu, c-preprocessor

If we use `__COUNTER__` in two different source files, the value is reset back to zero. Is it possible to make the `__COUNTER__` scope global?

**File: file1.c**

```
int x=__COUNTER__;

int y=__COUNTER__;
```

**File: file2.c**

```
int a=__COUNTER__;

int b=__COUNTER__;
```

---

I would like to have all x, y, a & b to have unique initialized values.
In this case, x=a, y=b.

---

I also tried placing `__COUNTER__` in a common Header file. Result is same.

File: common.h

`#define VALUE __COUNTER__`

replace all `__COUNTER__` with VALUE in above files.

Comment: No, that's not possible as `__COUNTER__` works during preprocessing and doesn't know about other source files. You need to be a bit clever to get the desired effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preprocessor facility \_\_COUNTER\_\_ in Visual C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947594/preprocessor-facility-counter-in-visual-c)

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu No. That question is about a different language with a different toolchain. Not applicable.

Comment: @FUZxxl retracted, thanks!

Comment: Global where? On your computer? On your network? In the entire world of C programs?

Answer (score 5):

You can compile your project so that each file has [an individual offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932774/reset-counter-macro-to-zero) (big enough, like 100) to `__COUNTER__` and use that offset to have individual counters.

```
==> file1.c <==
int x = COUNTER;
int y = COUNTER;


==> file2.c <==
int a = COUNTER;
int b = COUNTER;

==> main.c <==
#include <stdio.h>
extern int a, b, x, y;
int main() {
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a, b, x, y);
}
```

Such project configured with CMake with:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(test)
file(GLOB srcs *.c)

set(ii 0)
foreach(ff IN LISTS srcs)
  set_source_files_properties(${ff} PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS
      # add an offset to each file
      COUNTER_OFFSET=${ii}
  )
  # increment is by 100
  math(EXPR ii "${ii} + 100")
endforeach()
add_compile_definitions(
  # add COUNTER definition with the offset
  "COUNTER=(__COUNTER__+COUNTER_OFFSET)"
)

add_executable(test ${srcs})
```

So that each file has a separate unique offset, and `COUNTER` epxands to `__COUNTER__ + some offset`:

```
[1/4] /usr/bin/cc -DCOUNTER="(__COUNTER__+COUNTER_OFFSET)" -DCOUNTER_OFFSET=100 ...
[2/4] /usr/bin/cc -DCOUNTER="(__COUNTER__+COUNTER_OFFSET)" -DCOUNTER_OFFSET=200  ...
[3/4] /usr/bin/cc -DCOUNTER="(__COUNTER__+COUNTER_OFFSET)" -DCOUNTER_OFFSET=0 ...
```

The program outputs:

```
$ bin/test 
100 101 0 1
```

You could track how many times each file uses `COUNTER` with a regex, and then increment the offset only by the number of times `COUNTER` was used in the file, hopefully creating some limited continuous counting.