# Reset __COUNTER__ macro to zero

Tags: c++

is it possible to reset the `__COUNTER__` macro at the start of a header file to make its evaluation within the header file consistent over several compile units?

Comment: What is the `__COUNTER__` macro? Is it a compiler extension? For which compiler? Can you provide a link to the documentation for it?

Comment: I presume you are using gcc.  If you look at the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) `__COUNTER__` is a helper to enable unique identifiers, therefore even if it were possible you should not reset it.

Answer (score 10):

How about an enum?

```
enum { COUNTER_BASE = __COUNTER__ };

#define LOCAL_COUNTER (__COUNTER__ - COUNTER_BASE)
```

Comment: THIS works perfectly, is simple, and totally ignored by everyone!  This should be the accepted answer, hands down!

Comment: I will just add that the formula should be:  
  
```(__COUNTER__ - COUNTER_BASE - 1)```

Comment: Perfect!   This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

You can set `BASE` to `__COUNTER__` at the top of your header file, and then use `__COUNTER__ - BASE` later on.

However, do this *after* you've included all necessary headers, because else thee result would depend on the use of `__COUNTER__`  within the header guards of those nested include files.

Comment: If you would need a zero based counter BASE should be set to __COUNTER__ + 1

Comment: Because of preprocessor expansion, does `__COUNTER__ - BASE` count as one reference to `__COUNTER__` or two references?

Comment: I don't think this works... each reference of BASE is replaced by __COUNTER__ and thus depending on order of evaluation, the result will always be 1 or -1.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to reset that value.

Take a look at the [GCC source](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-7_3_0-release/libcpp/macro.c#L408) that increments the counter:

```
case BT_COUNTER:
    if (CPP_OPTION (pfile, directives_only) && pfile->state.in_directive)
    cpp_error (pfile, CPP_DL_ERROR,
        "__COUNTER__ expanded inside directive with -fdirectives-only");
    number = pfile->counter++;
    break;
```

And if you look arount this library, nowhere is the `counter` modified again. It is default initialized to `0` and then incremented at every use.

Note that the `pfile`, where the `counter` variable resides, represents the the preprocessor input, that in this case is the current compilation unit, not the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Michael, and by using enum you can have complete usage of `__COUNTER__` as below:

"source: [ESF compiler extension](https://github.com/reza69askari/ESF/blob/main/esf_compiler.h)"

```
//! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Counter >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
#pragma region Counter

/* Counter
 * Ex:
 * <code>
CountOn(InitSteps);
int foo(void)
{
    CountIt();
    ...
    CountIt();
    ...
    CountIt();
    ...
}
Counted(InitSteps);
 * </code>
 * */
#define CountOn(name)               enum { name ## _BASE = __COUNTER__ }; const U8 name
#define CountIt(name)               (U8)(__COUNTER__ - (name ## _BASE))
#define Counted(name)               const U8 name = (U8)(__COUNTER__ - (name ## _BASE) -1);

/* alias of Counter
 * Ex:
 * <code>
TakeSteps(InitSteps);
int foo(void)
{
    AddStep();
    ...
    AddStep();
    ...
    AddStep();
    ...
}
TotalSteps(InitSteps);
 * </code>
 * */
#define TakeSteps(name)             CountOn(name)
/* this is invalid to read, want to get value ? use 'CountIt(name)' OR 'NextStep(name)' */
#define AddStep()                   do { __COUNTER__; } while (0);
#define TotalSteps(name)            Counted(name)
/* better use of Counter (on format print 'step, total')
 * 'step' starts at 1
 * Ex:
 * <code>
TakeSteps(InitSteps);
int foo(void)
{
    printf(StepsPRT " Initializing system clock...", NextStep(InitSteps));
    ...
    printf(StepsPRT " Loading configurations...", NextStep(InitSteps));
    ...
    printf(StepsPRT " Applying...", NextStep(InitSteps));
    ...
}
TotalSteps(InitSteps);
 * </code>
 * */
#define NextStep(name)              CountIt(name), name
#define StepsPRT                    "%d of %d"
#define NextStepP                   StepsPRT

#pragma endregion Counter
//! <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< .Counter <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```